# Inconvenientes en la transaccion en mi procedimiento almacenado utilizando .net core 7

Tags: c#, .net, stored-procedure, transact-sql, dapper

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente: Estoy utilizando .NET 7 con dapper, para la ejecución de procedimientos almacenados. Pasa que hay casos dónde necesito crear una transacción padre, que en caso de que halla algún error con la inserción de varios registros, me deshaga la transacción, es decir, no me haga cambios en la base de datos; cuando lo ejecuto la primera vez, no me lanza inconvenientes, pero cuando lo ejecuto por segunda vez, me indica lo siguiente mensaje,

```
Ya se encuentra un registro en el sistema, con este codigo\r\nTransaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0.
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En teoria si estoy utilizando transaccion scope y utilizo el método Complete, no tengo que hacer un Dispose, pero me indica ese mensaje cuando lo ejecuto más de una vez.

Este es mi procedimiento almacenado:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GenderSave
(
     @GenderId CHAR(1)
    ,@GenderName NVARCHAR(10)
    ,@CreateBy NVARCHAR(60)
    ,@CreationDate DATETIME
    ,@ModifiedBy NVARCHAR(60)
    ,@ModifiedDate DATETIME
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;
    DECLARE @TRANCOUNT INT;
    SET @TRANCOUNT = @@TRANCOUNT;
    BEGIN TRY
        IF @TRANCOUNT = 0
            BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        ELSE
            SAVE TRANSACTION GenderSave;

                IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Genders AS g WHERE g.GenderId = @GenderId)
                    BEGIN
                        RAISERROR('Ya se encuentra un registro en el sistema, con este codigo', 12, 1);
                        RETURN;
                    END

                IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Genders AS g WHERE UPPER(g.GenderName) = UPPER(@GenderName))
                    BEGIN
                        RAISERROR('Ya se encuentra un registro en el sistema, con este genero', 12, 1);
                        RETURN;
                    END
                
                INSERT INTO Genders
                    (
                      GenderId
                     ,GenderName
                     ,CreateBy
                     ,CreationDate
                     ,ModifiedBy
                     ,ModifiedDate
                    )
                OUTPUT inserted.GenderId,
                       inserted.GenderName,
                       inserted.CreateBy,
                       inserted.CreationDate,
                       inserted.ModifiedBy,
                       inserted.ModifiedDate
                VALUES (
                      @GenderId
                     ,@GenderName
                     ,@CreateBy
                     ,@CreationDate
                     ,@ModifiedBy
                     ,@ModifiedDate
                    );

        IF @TRANCOUNT = 0   
            COMMIT;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @ERRORNUMBER INT, @MESSAGE NVARCHAR(4000), @XACT_STATE INT;
        SELECT @ERRORNUMBER = ERROR_NUMBER(), @MESSAGE = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @XACT_STATE = XACT_STATE();
        IF @XACT_STATE = -1
            ROLLBACK;
        IF @XACT_STATE = 1 AND @TRANCOUNT = 0
            ROLLBACK;
        IF @XACT_STATE = 1 AND @TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION GenderSave;

        RAISERROR(@MESSAGE, 16, 1);
    END CATCH
END
GO
```

Y este es el código de la transacción, que estoy utilizando transactionscope para manejar esta parte,

```
public async Task<BaseResponse<GenderResponseDto>> Handle(CreateGenderCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    BaseResponse<GenderResponseDto> response = new BaseResponse<GenderResponseDto>();

    try
    {
        using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable }, TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
        {

            Gender gender = await _genderRepository.SaveGender(_mapper.Map<Gender>(request));

            response.IsSuccess = true;
            response.Data = _mapper.Map<GenderResponseDto>(gender);
            response.Message = GlobalMessages.MESSAGE_SAVE;

            transactionScope.Complete();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        response.Message = ex.Message;
    }

    return response;
}
```

Quedo atento a sus comentarios, agradecería su ayuda,

Comment: La causa de este error es que al ejecutar tu procedimiento lo haces dentro de una transacción, por lo que al ingresar al procedimiento el contador de transacciones está en 1 que es la transacción desde donde se hizo la llamada, seguramente la segunda vez que lo ejecutas se produce un error por lo que llega al catch, en el cual haces un rollback, esto hace rollback de todas las transacciones, incluyendo la externa, si luego haces llamado de commit o rollback en la transacción externa se produce ese error.

Comment: Debes modificar tus validaciones teniendo en cuenta que estás llamando el procedimiento dentro de otra transacción.